Inverse of smooth curves on a manifold are smooth
Consider the following definition of smooth maps on closed sets (taken from Lee’s Smooth Manifolds):

Suppose $A \subset M$, a manifold, is closed, and $f:A \rightarrow R^k$. Then, $f$ is smooth if $\forall p \in A, \exists W_p \subset M$,
open, and $f_p: W_p \rightarrow R^k$, such that $f_p|_{W_p \cap A} = f|_{W_p \cap A}%%%%%%$.

Now, given a smooth (regular, if needed) curve $c:I \rightarrow M$, do we have that $c^{-1}:c(I) \rightarrow I$ is smooth in the above sense? In particular, I’m struggling to see what the local smooth extensions of the curve would be.
But at the same time, smooth (regular) functions do have smooth inverses often, so this seems true intuitively.

You may need the Lemma 5.34 (Extension Lemma for Functions on Submanifolds) or Proposition 5.2 (Images of Embeddings as Submanifolds) from the same book?

I think Lemma 5.34 answers my question but unfortunately it’s proof is left as an exercise in the textbook (and I’m not sure how to proceed).

As you've quoted that definition, it is trivial that every map $f$ is smooth, as you've stated no conditions at all on $f_p$ other than being equal to $f$ when restricted. Thus $f_p(q) = \begin{cases}f(q)&q\in A\0&q\notin A\end{cases}$ always satisfies the requirement.

As for proving the result, take the $W_p$ to be the domain of a chart on $M$ about $p$, then the problem reduces to whether the same result can be proven for a curve in $\Bbb R^d$ where $d$ is the dimension of $M$. Now you can various algebraic results to extend $c$ to a neighborhood of an embedding of $I$ into $\Bbb R^d$
